# Invoke step function in account A from a lambda in account B using cdk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I have a lambda stack that is deployed in account A, and a stepfunction stack deployer in account B. Now How do I invoke this stepfunction from the lambda using python cdk? specifically what permissions do i need to give them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda (Account A) has an IAM role(RoleA) assigned. The Step function (Account B) has an IAM role (RoleB) assigned.

#### Permissions

1. The lambda's IAM role should have permission to assume the role from (Account B)

   ```
   {
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
       {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
         "Resource": "*"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
2. The Step functions IAM role(Role B) should have a trusted policy that allows the Lambda's IAM role to assume it. in the following trust policy `123456789012` is the account number of Account A

   ```
   {
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
       {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
           "AWS": [
             "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:root"
           ]
         },
         "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

#### Inside the lambda

1. The lambda should have code that assumes the role(Role B) from Account B and get temporary credentials
2. Using those credentials the lambda should invoke the step function.

[How to assume an IAM role in a different account from lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger something when a cdk deployment happens:

Seems a bizarre use-case but I think the solution here is to define a custom resource.
Both cdk and cloudformation support that:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/custom-resources-readme.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html

Because you are using a custom resource you would need to further handle Create, Update, Delete events by yourself. Similarly send completion responses, I would advice you to use cfnresponsemodule to send back completion responses otherwise cdk will never be able to tell when your custom resource function completed:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-lambda-function-code-cfnresponsemodule.html